# Is there a bijection from the set of sequences of 0s and 1s to the reals? Is there a bijection from the set of sequences of reals to the reals?

Tags: real-analysis, cardinals

Is there a bijection from the set of sequences of 0s and 1s to the reals?  I believe this is true since every real number cab be represented as a binary.  But I do not know how to do so.

Is there a bijection from the set of sequences of reals to the reals?  Could this just be placing each digit of the unique decimal representation of a number into a sequence and vice versa?

Comment: Yes and yes.${}$

Comment: Can you show me an argument or construction?

Comment: From the dialog that appeared when you clicked "Ask Question: "2. Provide details and any research  3. When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried".  Can you show any research or describe what you've tried?

Comment: For bijection you need to show that works both ways. For example, in the first case, can any sequence of $0$ and $1$ be a real? Or in the second case, if you have a sequence of **reals**, say $\{e,\pi,\sqrt 2\}$, how would you represent it as a unique real number?